# Infinite amount of generators for a finite cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra

We can find the number of elements in a cyclic group generated by a number by taking the gcd of the two numbers.

Suppose we want to find the number of elements in the cyclic subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_5$ generated by $4$? Well gcd(5,4) = 1 and $\frac{5}{1} = 5$. This tells us that $4$ is relatively prime to $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and generates every element in the cyclic group.

**I am not sure if my thinking is correct here:**

Suppose now that we want to find the number of elements in the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_5$ generated by 6. Well gcd(5,6) is 1, which makes 6 relatively prime and a generator for every element in the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Here now I am thinking that there are an infinite amount of numbers that can be relatively prime to $\mathbb{Z}_5 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore there are an infinite amount of generators for $\mathbb{Z}_5$ and more generally for a finite cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Comment: A finite cyclic group $C_n$ has only finitely many elements. So it can only have finitely many generators, too. Note that $g^6=g$ is not a new element in $C_5$, for example.

Comment: Why is it important to note that $g^6 = g$ is not a new element in $C_5$?

Comment: Because you have argued that $g,g^6,g^{11},g^{16}, \cdots $ are infinitely many generators. But they are all the same element. All numbers $1,6,11,16,\cdots $ are of course relatively prime to $5$.

Comment: The infinitely many numbers you refer to fall into $5$ residue classes (within which elements are considered to be equal), in $C_5$.

Comment: So there are an infinite amount of numbers within each residue class that are equal to each other so my logic is flawed because I am counting these equal numbers an infinite amount of times.

Comment: Yes Evan.  That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually $\varphi (n)$ generators for $\Bbb Z_n$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.

Numbers greater than $n$ which are relatively prime to $n$ fall into equivalence classes which can be represented by numbers less than $n$;  that is, by the $n$ residues $0,1,\dots, n-1$ modulo $n$.